# AWS QuickSight, How to add new calculated filed which is Sum of column value till the current row

Tags: amazon-web-services, dataset, calculated-columns, amazon-quicksight

I am new to QuickSight, I want to know how to add a calculated field that will result in giving the sum up until that particular row.

Say I have a donation data set with given below columns.

| Name | Mode | donation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Rahul | Cash | 100 |
| David | Online | 150 |
| Adam | Cash | 200 |

...

Now I want to add a calculated field (total so far) that should give the total of the donation until that row, as below

| Name | Mode | donation | Total so far |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Rahul | Cash | 100 | 100 |
| David | Online | 150 | 250 |
| Adam | Cash | 200 | 450 |

Basically Total so far column is current row donation + the sum of previous donations. I don't want a visual but I want as data set itself, how can I do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [runningSum function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/runningSum-function.html)

If you want to have this sorted by a particular field then that goes at the end in the square brackets, I am using "Name" in ascending order in the following example

```
runningSum
(
  {donation},
  [{Name} ASC]  
)
```

Comment: Thanks, This helped. This is what I was looking for. 

Accepted the answer. I Can't upvote as new User.